# "Unsubscribe" for email categories/types through Sendgrid, Mailchimp, SES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I've got a Rails 3.2 app that will need to send various transactional & bulk (marketing) types of emails. Ideally I'd be able to use a service (like Sendgrid or Amazon SES) to improve deliverability and for unsubscribe support. I've mostly used Sendgrid in the past, but I need the 'unsubscribe' to be just for a specific category of the email (there are around 6 categories). I can't have someone unsubscribing from a marketing email and miss out on notification or invitation emails. Does anyone know of an service that supports this, or does this just have to be done internally? It seems like there's a lot to deal with related to best practices for deliverability, list-unsubscribe, etc. if you manage it yourself.

I see this discussion on sendgrid, but seems to be pending still:
http://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid/topics/unsubscribe_and_categories

I'm happy to go with any service if it integrates relatively easily with Rails and can support category/type based subscription management. Or perhaps a hybrid approach with different services or separate accounts on the same service, if they allow that for the same domain?

I very much appreciate any feedback on how others have tackled this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like CritSend(1) have what they call "tag" support and state the following [on their site](http://www.critsend.com/compliance/):

> Our unsub processing is done per tag, so if someone unsubscribes from
> one of your emails tagged "newsletter1" that does not unsubscribe them
> from any other tag.

The one thing that is unclear is the level of Ruby support.

CritSend name MxmConnect as the gem to use for sending emails. There is a [critsend_events](https://github.com/cutalion/critsend_events) gem for the CritSend Events API.

(1) Note, I have no affiliation with CritSend

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll check out CritSend. Their ruby support seems to be lacking: http://www.critsend.com/ruby-example/ is a coming soon page, and the gem they reference (MxmConnect) seems pretty outdated. I'm not sure I'd need the Events API...But probably worth giving it a shot and seeing how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: The critsend_events was made by a third party, the MxMConnect Gem is Critsend's own gem.  The Events API isn't needed and you can get most data from the online dashboards, but the Event API can help with integrating Critsend into your code.

Answer (score 2):

SendGrid is currently developing this feature and we hope to have it out shortly. There isn't an exact time for the release of this feature yet but it sounds like it is just what you are looking for.  Check out SendGrid's blog, it will be updated when this feature is available for beta testing.

http://www.sendgrid.com/blog

Thanks
Brian

Comment: Yes, I'd love to use Sendgrid for this as the the API and ruby support will likely be much better. Do you have a rough estimate on how long 'shortly' may be? A month? 6 months? I could probably stall on the feature for a month but not 6 ;-)

Comment: This was over a year ago and the api doc still mentions global unsubscribe only (or per list, if using the marketing email api).